# Can subversion append revision id to file?

Tags: svn

I would like to contain some meta data in some versioned non-code-level files, specifically the revision ID of the file. If possible, I would like to configure a specific directory so that whenever a file is checked in, the `subversion` server takes the new revision number and append

> /* rev: $revNo */

to the end of the file. The thing is, a script that processes these versioned files would like to know what the revision of the file is and reading the last line in the file, which is entered in a format that doesn't break the rest of the file's semantics, would be easier than using some svn API to check the file revision or even invoking a system level svn command against that versioned object.

Is there a way to automate this task?

Answer (score 2):

## Server

Not sure if this can be done on the server side.  I assume it can.  The server would need a [pre-commit hook](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) to perform the action.  This might be server-specific.  In [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/), you can write a [power-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) script which is called pre-commit with the following ordered arguments:

```
[1] REPOS-PATH 
[2] REV 
[3] TXN-NAME.
```

I *think* you could use these parameters to append that information to a versioned file.  I'm just not sure if that would trigger another commit, triggering another pre-commit hook.

## Client

You could definitely do something similar on the client side.  I use [SubWCRev](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html).  It's part the [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) which uses command-line interface to get SVN parameters.

With a file: SubWC.h.in:

```
#define SVNREV "$WCREV$"
#define SVNMOD "$WCMODS?Modified:Not modified$";
#define SVNVER "$WCUNVER?Unversioned items found:no unversioned items$";
```

Then if you run `SubWCRev.exe . SubWC.h.in SubWC.h` during a pre-build event, you'll get an auto-generated header:

```
#define SVNREV "2345"
#define SVNMOD "Modified"
#define SVNVER "Unversioned items found"
```

You can `#include` that header to embed version info in your application.

There's a good explanation of that [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev-example.html).  It doesn't version the generated file for you, but you could probably script an `svn ci` in that same pre-build script.

Comment: I would recommend against doing that via hook script -- don't modify transactions and revisions via hook scripts. However, appending the custom ID in form of some unversioned property such as `customprop:name=MyIDNumber` will work in some cases and may be sufficient.